# python - translate number of coordinates to address or city

Tags: python, google-geocoder, geocode

I have 245,000 coordinates. I want to translate these coordinates to city name.

But there is a limit(2,500 requests/day) for using Google Maps Geocoding API.

Is there any other solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapzen will give you 30,000 requests per day and it is really easy to use their API: https://mapzen.com/documentation/search/api-keys-rate-limits/#rate-limits .  It's completely free, and quick and easy to get an API key.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)